# How to create a Multidimensional Arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Dear experts I'm new in PHP and MYsql. Please if possible give me a hints how to create a Multidimensional array with output data from queries.

My queries result is as bellow:

```
[
    {"uid":29,"totalAmount":"5400.00"},
    {"uid":499,"totalAmount":"5400.00"},
    {"uid":507,"totalAmount":"3960.00"},
    {"uid":497,"totalAmount":"3960.00"},
    {"uid":498,"totalAmount":"3960.00"},
    {"uid":34,"totalAmount":"3960.00"},
    {"uid":21,"totalAmount":"3240.00"},
    {"uid":27,"totalAmount":"2880.00"},
    {"uid":500,"totalAmount":"2880.00"},
    {"uid":19,"totalAmount":"2700.00"},
    {"uid":22,"totalAmount":"2700.00"},
    {"uid":20,"totalAmount":"2520.00"},
    {"uid":23,"totalAmount":"2520.00"},
    {"uid":504,"totalAmount":"1800.00"},
    {"uid":496,"totalAmount":"1440.00"},
    {"uid":26,"totalAmount":"1260.00"},
    {"uid":491,"totalAmount":"1080.00"},
    {"uid":492,"totalAmount":"720.00"},
    {"uid":464,"totalAmount":"540.00"},
    {"uid":493,"totalAmount":"540.00"},
    {"uid":76,"totalAmount":"540.00"},
    {"uid":505,"totalAmount":"180.00"},
    {"uid":506,"totalAmount":"180.00"},
    {"uid":494,"totalAmount":"180.00"},
    {"uid":495,"totalAmount":"180.00"}
]
```

Now I want to create a multidimensional array as [ "1"=>["0"=>"5400.00", "1"=>5400.00], "2"=>["0"=>3960.00,"1"=>3960.00,"2"=>3960.00,"3"=>3960.00]] and as so on

Comment: what is input data? an array of strings, or JSON string ?

Comment: So is there anything you did try? And where exactly is the problem? This is not a "write-my-code" site.

Comment: use `json_decode` function

Comment: array of object @RomanPerekhrest

Comment: @afrajsarkar, what do you mean with "for similar totalAmount in one index" ? do you want to group all values from objects that have identical `"totalAmount"` value?

Comment: Yes @RomanPerekhrest actually I want to create a multidimensional array as [ "1"=>["0"=>"5400.00", "1"=>5400.00]] and as so on

Answer (score 1):

Use below code. You need to use `json_decode()`.

```
$json = '{"inbox":[{"uid":29,"totalAmount":"5400.00"},
{"uid":499,"totalAmount":"5400.00"},
{"uid":507,"totalAmount":"3960.00"},
{"uid":497,"totalAmount":"3960.00"},
{"uid":498,"totalAmount":"3960.00"},
{"uid":34,"totalAmount":"3960.00"},
{"uid":21,"totalAmount":"3240.00"},
{"uid":27,"totalAmount":"2880.00"},
{"uid":500,"totalAmount":"2880.00"},
{"uid":19,"totalAmount":"2700.00"},
{"uid":22,"totalAmount":"2700.00"},
{"uid":20,"totalAmount":"2520.00"},
{"uid":23,"totalAmount":"2520.00"},
{"uid":504,"totalAmount":"1800.00"},
{"uid":496,"totalAmount":"1440.00"},
{"uid":26,"totalAmount":"1260.00"},
{"uid":491,"totalAmount":"1080.00"},
{"uid":492,"totalAmount":"720.00"},
{"uid":464,"totalAmount":"540.00"},
{"uid":493,"totalAmount":"540.00"},
{"uid":76,"totalAmount":"540.00"},
{"uid":505,"totalAmount":"180.00"},
{"uid":506,"totalAmount":"180.00"},
{"uid":494,"totalAmount":"180.00"},
{"uid":495,"totalAmount":"180.00"}
]}';

$array = json_decode($json,true);

foreach ($array['inbox'] as $row)
{
    $rowArr = (array)$row;
    $totalAmountArr[] = $rowArr['totalAmount'];
}
print_r($totalAmountArr);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 5400.00
    [1] => 5400.00
    [2] => 3960.00
    [3] => 3960.00
    [4] => 3960.00
    [5] => 3960.00
    [6] => 3240.00
    [7] => 2880.00
    [8] => 2880.00
    [9] => 2700.00
    [10] => 2700.00
    [11] => 2520.00
    [12] => 2520.00
    [13] => 1800.00
    [14] => 1440.00
    [15] => 1260.00
    [16] => 1080.00
    [17] => 720.00
    [18] => 540.00
    [19] => 540.00
    [20] => 540.00
    [21] => 180.00
    [22] => 180.00
    [23] => 180.00
    [24] => 180.00
)
```

**Check Live Demo :  [Click Here](https://eval.in/556937)**

Comment: Check this answer 'totalAmount' in one index. @afraj sarkar

Comment: I have change it. Thanks @RyanVincent

Comment: Feel free to accept the correct answer. :) @afraj sarkar

Answer (score 0):

Use `json_decode` function. Online compile at [My answer](https://3v4l.org/hf7Do)

```
$arr_json = '[
{"uid":29,"totalAmount":"5400.00"},
{"uid":499,"totalAmount":"5400.00"},
{"uid":507,"totalAmount":"3960.00"},
{"uid":497,"totalAmount":"3960.00"},
{"uid":498,"totalAmount":"3960.00"},
{"uid":34,"totalAmount":"3960.00"},
{"uid":21,"totalAmount":"3240.00"},
{"uid":27,"totalAmount":"2880.00"},
{"uid":500,"totalAmount":"2880.00"},
{"uid":19,"totalAmount":"2700.00"},
{"uid":22,"totalAmount":"2700.00"},
{"uid":20,"totalAmount":"2520.00"},
{"uid":23,"totalAmount":"2520.00"},
{"uid":504,"totalAmount":"1800.00"},
{"uid":496,"totalAmount":"1440.00"},
{"uid":26,"totalAmount":"1260.00"},
{"uid":491,"totalAmount":"1080.00"},
{"uid":492,"totalAmount":"720.00"},
{"uid":464,"totalAmount":"540.00"},
{"uid":493,"totalAmount":"540.00"},
{"uid":76,"totalAmount":"540.00"},
{"uid":505,"totalAmount":"180.00"},
{"uid":506,"totalAmount":"180.00"},
{"uid":494,"totalAmount":"180.00"},
{"uid":495,"totalAmount":"180.00"}
]';


print_r(json_decode($arr_json));
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [uid] => 29
            [totalAmount] => 5400.00
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [uid] => 499
            [totalAmount] => 5400.00
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [uid] => 507
            [totalAmount] => 3960.00
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [uid] => 497
            [totalAmount] => 3960.00
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [uid] => 498
            [totalAmount] => 3960.00
        )

    [5] => stdClass Object
        (
            [uid] => 34
            [totalAmount] => 3960.00
        )

    [6] => stdClass Object
        (
            [uid] => 21
            [totalAmount] => 3240.00
        )

    [7] => stdClass Object
        (
            [uid] => 27
            [totalAmount] => 2880.00
        )

    [8] => stdClass Object
        (
            [uid] => 500
            [totalAmount] => 2880.00
        )

    [9] => stdClass Object
        (
            [uid] => 19
            [totalAmount] => 2700.00
        )

    [10] => stdClass Object
        (
            [uid] => 22
            [totalAmount] => 2700.00
        )

    [11] => stdClass Object
        (
            [uid] => 20
            [totalAmount] => 2520.00
        )

    [12] => stdClass Object
        (
            [uid] => 23
            [totalAmount] => 2520.00
        )

    [13] => stdClass Object
        (
            [uid] => 504
            [totalAmount] => 1800.00
        )

    [14] => stdClass Object
        (
            [uid] => 496
            [totalAmount] => 1440.00
        )

    [15] => stdClass Object
        (
            [uid] => 26
            [totalAmount] => 1260.00
        )

    [16] => stdClass Object
        (
            [uid] => 491
            [totalAmount] => 1080.00
        )

    [17] => stdClass Object
        (
            [uid] => 492
            [totalAmount] => 720.00
        )

    [18] => stdClass Object
        (
            [uid] => 464
            [totalAmount] => 540.00
        )

    [19] => stdClass Object
        (
            [uid] => 493
            [totalAmount] => 540.00
        )

    [20] => stdClass Object
        (
            [uid] => 76
            [totalAmount] => 540.00
        )

    [21] => stdClass Object
        (
            [uid] => 505
            [totalAmount] => 180.00
        )

    [22] => stdClass Object
        (
            [uid] => 506
            [totalAmount] => 180.00
        )

    [23] => stdClass Object
        (
            [uid] => 494
            [totalAmount] => 180.00
        )

    [24] => stdClass Object
        (
            [uid] => 495
            [totalAmount] => 180.00
        )

)
```